# Tableviewcells not appearing in tableView while iterating through an array. Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

So I have

```
NSEnumerator *e = [myWords objectEnumerator];
id object;
while (object = [e nextObject])
{
 UITableViewCell *newcell; 
newcell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
}
```

But I see no way to append it to the end of a tablieView.  Forgive my ignorance I am recently transitioning from Visual Studio where they requires less knowledge and do a bit more of this stuff for you via methods such as .append(object).  I have searched on stack overflow and frankly haven't found any example code while in this midst of an enumerator.

I appreciate the help.

KT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is totally different in iOS. You don't feed the cells directly to the tableview.

The tableview asks you for a cell and it only asks for visible cells.

Unless you read the tableview programming guide: [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)
you won't understand the mechanism.

- Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom it is a bit new going from Windows where you add.

Comment: @Kevrone: welcome to the "other side". When working with the iOS frameworks you'll discover that there often is a core functionality (here UITableView) that will take care of the details by using delegates and data sources, that you have to code.

Answer (score 0):

You add new cells from the [tableview datasource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), you can't add them directly. If you really want and need to add them directly use a `UIScrollView` and `UIViews` instead of `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` (this will also require that you position each view yourself.

You're also not initializing `newCell` in your example, so the while loop does nothing.

[Here](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/)'s a tutorial on how to use tableviews. Search on google 'uitableview example' and you'll find more.